# Eclipse 2019-12 showing error: JRE Private Build/14.0.1 is not supported, advanced source lookup disabled

Tags: java, eclipse

when i am running my debugger in eclipse it shows the error.
**JRE Private Build/14.0.1 is not supported, advanced source lookup disabled.**
Please if someone help for ubuntu 20.04.

Comment: Java 14 support is only in the current Eclipse 2020-06

Comment: In general, you want to use a release of Eclipse that came out *after* your JRE/JDK if you want it properly supported.